# Excel VBA - Copy and paste a range of cells when certain names match from one work book another

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project and I have got a point where I want to copy certain data from one sheet to another. E.g. if in column `"A"` a cell contains `"Hello"` then copy what is in cell "E4". Would an "IF" statement would work?

The code I have so far for my project is

```
Sub testfortito()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'this opens both workbooks
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("Location1")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("Location2")

    'to do the copy
    x.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2:AC2").Copy

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "sheet3" Then
            ws.Range("E3").Copy
            Worksheets ("Sheet3")
        End If    
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What you really want to do is to `Find` the desired cell's `Address` in `Column A` and then copy the content of corresponding `Column E`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub testfortito()
    Dim colEtxt(), ctr

    ctr = 0
    With Sheet1.Range("A:A")
        Set txt = .Find(What:="hello", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not txt Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = txt.Address
            Do
                ReDim Preserve colEtxt(ctr)
                colEtxt(ctr) = Range(txt.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value
                Set txt = .FindNext(txt)
                ctr = ctr + 1
            Loop While Not txt Is Nothing And txt.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

    'copy the array onto sheet2 using transpose technique
    Sheet2.Range("A1:A" & UBound(colEtxt) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(colEtxt)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will see what happens, currently I am getting stuck in a procedure before I hit this. As soon as I can test this out I will let you know if this works.